# Calling Perl Scripts from a Perl script given the scripts are in an array

Tags: perl

I have a list of perl scripts as sample_1.pl , sample_2.pl & sample_3.pl. stored in an array as

```
my @Scripts (
     sample_1 => "This is script number 1 ",
     sample_2 => "This is script number 2 ",
     sample_3 => "This is script number 3 "
)
```

Now how do I call these scripts using foreach loop

Comment: What do you mean by calling these script? You could include this using use  $file in foreach loop, and call subroutines of these files.

Comment: Use [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)

Comment: There's a `=` missing after `my @Scripts`.

Comment: Also, why do you need the values ("This is script number...")?

Comment: @Sebastian: Please don't edit posts to include assumptions of your own. We don't really know what the OP means at this point

Comment: That code looks like a hash literal being assigned to an array. It will assign six string elements to the array `@Scripts`. Although it's valid Perl, it's probably not what you meant, and it's really hard to tell what you *did* mean. Please help us out

Comment: @Borodin: He said *I have a list of perl scripts as sample_1.pl , sample_2.pl & sample_3.pl. stored in an array as*, that's why I did the edit. The missing "=" should be added anyway.

Comment: @Sebastian: No, the `=` should not be added anyway. You have no idea what the real code contains, if there even is any. It's fine to add *insignificant white space* to code, but never to rewrite its meaning

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, it's not clear whether you want to store your commands in an array or a hash. The two data structures are different in Perl. In your code, you store the commands in an array (`@Scripts`) but you initialise that array using a very hash-like syntax (`(key => value, ...)`). Your syntax will work, but it doesn't do what (I think!) you want to do. You also end up with your keys in the array, and it's hard to skip them.

If you want to store your commands in an array, then do something like this:

```
my @Scripts = (
  "This is script number 1 ",
  "This is script number 2 ",
  "This is script number 3 "
);

system($_) for @Scripts;
```

If you want to store them in a hash for some reason, then store them in a has and use a hash function to get the values you want.

```
my %Scripts = ( # %, not @ for a hash
  sample_1 => "This is script number 1 ",
  sample_2 => "This is script number 2 ",
  sample_3 => "This is script number 3 "
);

system($_) for values %Scripts;
```

But note that hashes are un-ordered, so you won't be able to control the order in which your commands are executed.

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps. From the question I think it's far more likely that the OP intended `system $_ for map "$_.pl", keys %Scripts`. Either way, you have jumped in with a speculative answer when more information is required, presumably in the hope of farming points. I wish people wouldn't do that

Comment: My answer certainly wasn't posted for the purpose of collecting points. I have plenty of points, I really don't need any more. I think my answer was worth posting for two reasons - firstly it's important to clear up the confusion between arrays and hashes and secondly, it demonstrates the use of `system()` which is going to be at the heart of any answer to this question. It's true that we need more details of the contents of the array (or hash) in order to give a truly accurate answer, but I think mine is pretty close given the information that we currently have. Sorry that you don't agree.

Answer (score 2):

```
my @scripts = ("print 'Hello, omg'", "print 42");
eval $_ for @scripts
```

If you intend to do use them many times in a single script run, you'd better store compiled versions rather than source codes:

```
my @scripts = map eval "sub { $_ }", "print 'Hello, omg'", "print 42";
$_->() for @scripts
```

It will be order of magnitude faster.